# How can I call an Adobe InDesign javascript from another InDesign javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have so many javascripts in InDesign, I wrote a script that lists them all so I can select from them. The problem is getting the "directory" javascript to call the selected javascript. How can one javascript in InDesign call another?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var main = function() {
 var fo = Folder.selectDialog(),
 jsxs, jsx,
 fn = function(f) {
  return /\.jsx?$/i.test ( f.name );
 };
 
 if ( !fo ) return;
 
 jsxs = fo.getFiles ( fn );
 
 
 while ( jsx = jsxs.pop() ) {
  app.doScript ( jsx );
 }
}

main();
```

You might need to introduce user interaction level to avoid pop up warnings.